# Synth for music like Fennesz

Tags: synthesizer

what synth would I need to make ambient and granular music like Fennesz? Probably a granular synth?

Comment: Are you asking which exact synth or which type of synth? It’s off topic to ask for a recommendation for an exact synth. The question about which type doesn’t have a solid answer: you can make any kind of music with any kind of synth.

Comment: Native Instruments' Reaktor software has granular synthesis modules that you can use to build your own instrument; so you could build something that gives you the control to sound like this. The Max software (or its version for Ableton Live) can probably do this, too. Software like that has a learning curve, but you'll probably have a better chance of finding the exact sound you like, than if you bought a hardware synth or sampler.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I was asking which type of synth, then i'll be able to choose one by myself. So do you mean I can make a granular sound with any synth like for example with a subtractive or wavetable ones?

Comment: Yes, you can make sounds like that with almost any kind of synth. I agree it does sound like granular synthesis was used for at least some of the sounds, but since those sounds could have been made with other types of synthesis, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: That seems like bad advice. You surely cannot make these sounds with "almost any kind of synth"; sampling, wavetable, granular... yes; analog subtractive, FM, additive... no.